# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on very simple code

Tags: objective-c, ios-4.2

I am using the nav controller and pushing another view into the stack and setting a variable too. While trying to access the variable I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS :(

Here's the code (I am not using any NIB) :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface detailedView : UIViewController {

NSString *movieName2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *movieName2;

@end
```

and

```
#import "detailedView.h"


@implementation detailedView

@synthesize movieName2;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

self.view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(213, 300, 355, 315);
self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];



self.title=self.movieName2;
NSLog(@"%@",movieName2);
}
```

Relevant code in the caller function :

```
detailedView *details;


@property (nonatomic, retain) detailedView *details;
```

//properly synthesized and released

````
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSLog(@"Did Reach inside...");

status=1;

self.title=@"Back";
details.movieName2=self.movieName;

NSLog(@"```");
NSLog(@"2nd VC %@ sdfsdf",details.movieName2); //Getting the ERROR here
NSLog(@"1st VC %@ wrewrw",self.movieName);
//viewerSearch *viewerSearchController=[[viewerSearch alloc] init];



[[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:NO];    

}
````

init:

```
 details=[[detailedView alloc] init];
```

//movieName is a NSString and has    @property(nonatomic,copy)

Comment: Where does the error occur? And are you using a NIB?

Comment: @Deepak : I am not using a NIB. The error occurs on the line :NSLog(@"2nd VC %@ sdfsdf",details.movieName2);

Comment: @Deepak : you mean the error message ? I am not sure how to get crash logs ! any help on that ?

Comment: Where does movieName get initialised/set ? From the code as given it looks like it's just a dangling pointer which then gets copied to details.movieName2 ?

Answer (score 1):

**When an app crashes, there will be a crash log or you'll be able to get a backtrace from the debugger.  Always post that.**

Also -- class names should always start with a capital letter.

Try Build and Analyze;  make sure your memory management is correct.

Then turn on Zombie detection once you fix any build and analyze found problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a test by calling a `retain` on a `alloc-init-release`d `NSString` and then following it up by logging it, I think your problem is that `self.movieName` is deallocated. Please check whether the memory management rules have been properly followed with regards to `self.movieName`.

On a side note, if you are not using a NIB for `detailedView` then you should create the view in `loadView` and not `viewDidAppear:` as you seem to be doing. `viewWillAppear:` only if the view exists, right? I suggest you move the related code from `viewDidAppear:` to `loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always copy strings instead of retaining them.
So changing

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *movieName2;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *movieName2;
```

will probably fix your problem.

Also, if you create the value in `self.movieName` with `@"something"`, do not release the value.

Comment: Why should you "always copy strings instead of retaining them"? This sounds like horrible advice.

Comment: I can't find a definite statement from Apple right now, but look at all NSString properties of Apple's own classes, e.g the title property on UIViewController: they are copied.

See also Google's Objective-C style guide: 
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml

Comment: Hmm. My suspicion is that they're trying to avoid having the property set to a NSMutableString that may change. But I view it as the responsibility of the caller to specify an immutable string, not the object.